# VSCode Pylance shows [reportMissingImports] while importing some of tensorflow submodules

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, conda, pylance

I'm using conda environment in vscode. TensorFlow is installed and can be used properly. But Pylance show `[reportMissingImports]` in some of imported submodules or classes, etc. For example, refer to the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcVOS.png

The squiggled submodules couldn't be resolved by Pylance, and the intellisense and autocompletion are invalid, which is very disruptive to coding. In contrast, the unsquiggled modules, just like `tf` and `keras` in the screenshot, work well.

###### Version Lists

```
python 3.10.13
TensorFlow 2.11.1
vscode 1.84.2
Pylance 2023.11.10
```

I have confirmed that I choose the right Python interpreter. Actually, TensorFlow works well while running my codes. I notice that when I type `import tensorflow.python.` the autocompletion only shows `keras` submodule. Please refer to the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRn5.png

Is Pylance bugged, or should anything else be set to ensure Pylance works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the resolution according to https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/734.
As the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/yksy2.png, it does work well, as my expect.